# Generate random tree using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, tree, logic

I am working on a project to generate random data structures for testing solutions for DSA problems. I am trying to form an algorithm that generates a random tree data structure that takes in the input of *number of test cases* and *number of nodes*. Since I cannot use pointers and references, I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this in javaScript.

So far I managed to get the basics down, however, I'm getting errors in my code

### **CODE:**

```js
const randnumgen = (min, max) => {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
};

function randtreegen(nodes) {

  var string = "";

  class Tree {

    constructor(nodes) {
      this.nodes = nodes;
      this.adj = [];
    }
    addEdge(n, w) {
      this.adj[n].push(w);
    }
    removeEdge(n, w) {
      this.adj[n].forEach((elem) => {
        if (elem === w) {
          var index = this.adj[n].indexOf(elem);
          if (index !== -1) this.adj[n].splice(index, 1);
        }
      });
    }
    isCyclicUtil(nodes, visited, recStack) {
      if (visited[nodes] === false) {
        visited[nodes] = true;
        recStack[nodes] = true;

        this.adj[n].forEach((elem) => {
          if (!visited[elem] && this.isCyclicUtil(elem, visited, recStack))
            return true;
          else if (recStack[elem])
            return true;
        });
      }
      recStack[nodes] = false;
      return false;
    }
    isCyclic() {

      visited = new Array();
      recStack = new Array();

      for (var i = 0; i < this.nodes; i++) {
        visited[i] = false;
        recStack[i] = false;
      }

      for (var j = 0; j < this.nodes; i++) {
        if (this.isCyclicUtil(j, visited, recStack))
          return true;
      }

      return false;
    }
  }

  container = new Set();
  let t = new Tree(nodes);
  for (var i = 1; i < nodes - 1; i++) {
    var a = randnumgen(1, nodes);
    var b = randnumgen(1, nodes);
    var p = [a, b];

    t.addEdge(p[0], p[1]);

    while (container.has(`${p[0]},${p[1]}`) || t.isCyclic() === true) {
      t.removeEdge(p[0], p[1]);

      var a = randnumgen(1, nodes);
      var b = randnumgen(1, nodes);
      var p = [a, b];

      t.addEdge(p[0], p[1]);
    }
    container.add(`${p[0]},${p[1]}`);
  }

  container.forEach((elem) => {
    string += elem + '\n'
  });
  return string;
}


function treeGen(test_case, tree_nodes) {
  var result = "";
  while (test_case-- > 0) {
    result += randtreegen(tree_nodes) + '\n';
  }
  return result;
}

const ans = treeGen(1, 5);

document.write(ans);
```

---

## ERROR

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined at /home/cg/root/7217808/main.js:18
        this.adj[n].push(w);
```

### My question is:

- Is the Logic correct?
- How to resolve the error to make it work?

P.S: I referred to [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/test-case-generation-set-4-random-directed-undirected-weighted-and-unweighted-graphs/) article on GeeksforGeeks.

Comment: So your graph is directed. When you want it to be a tree, do you consider the directed edges to go from parent to child, or from child to parent?

Comment: I want to create a directed unweighted tree and directed edges to go from parent to child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you have not created the `adj` entries as empty arrays. So change:

```
  this.adj = [];
```

To:

```
  this.adj = Array.from({length: nodes}, () => []); // create that many empty arrays
```

But there are other issues as well:

- Some pieces of code expect that nodes are numbered from 1, while other pieces of code expect a numbering starting at 0. As array indexes start from 0, it is more natural to also number your nodes starting from 0.
- There are references to an unknown variable `n`, which should be `nodes`. NB: It is strange that you choose a plural name for this variable.
- When you `return true` inside a `forEach` callback, you don't return from the outer function, but only from the `forEach` callback. This is not what you intended. Solve this by using a `for...of` loop.
- In `isCyclic` you have a loop on `j`, but you increment with `i++`, so this loop will never end. Make it `j++`
- The cycle test is not enough to ensure that your graph is a tree, because in a directed graph you can still have multiple paths between a node A and a node B, without cycles.
- The loop in which edges are created needs one more iteration, so let it start from 0.

I would however suggest a slightly different approach for generating a random tree: shuffle all nodes randomly, and let the first node in that shuffled array be the root of the tree. Iterate all the other nodes, and let them be the destinations of new edges. Note that in a tree there is no node in which two edges arrive.

Then you can do a cycle test. I would however do this different too: perform a test *before* adding the edge. You can get all descendent nodes of the selected `b` node, and if `a` is in that set, then you should not create edge `a,b`.

Here is your adapted code. I removed the parts that are no longer used:

```js
function randnumgen (min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

class Tree {
    constructor(nodes) {
        this.nodes = nodes;
        this.adj = Array.from({length: nodes}, () => []);
    }
    addEdge(n, w) {
        this.adj[n].push(w);
    }
    descendants(node) {
        let visited = new Set([node]);
        for (let node of visited) {
            for (let elem of this.adj[node]) {
                if (!visited.has(elem)) visited.add(elem);
            }
        }
        return visited;
    }
}

function shuffle(array) {
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        var temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
    return array;
}

function randtreegen(nodes) {
    let t = new Tree(nodes);
    let [root, ...children] = shuffle([...Array(nodes).keys()]);
    let edges = [];
    let a;
    for (let b of children) {
        do {
            a = randnumgen(0, nodes-1); // make zero based
        } while (t.descendants(b).has(a));
        t.addEdge(a, b);
        edges.push([a, b]);
    }
    return edges.join("\n");
}

function treeGen(test_case, tree_nodes) {
    var result = "";
    while (test_case-- > 0) {
        result += randtreegen(tree_nodes) + '\n';
    }
    return result;
}

const ans = treeGen(1, 5);

console.log(ans);
```