# Dictionary: Map vs Object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dictionary, object, data-structures

In JavaScript, both `Object` and `Map` can be used for "Dictionary" (key-value pairs store) as they let you perform all the basic read and write operations you would expect when working with such a data structure: "set", "get", "delete" and "detect" keys, value & entries. Historically, and before `Map` even exists in JavaScript, we have been using `Object` for dictionaries. That's perfectly fine, however, there are important differences that make `Map` preferable in some cases and that could be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#objects_vs._maps

Personally, in the case that I am currently working on, I would like to use `Map` over `Object` because I feel that `Map` would be more suited for what I am trying to achieve at the moment: huge dictionary with hundred millions entries, lots of read/write operations, and based on custom benchmark, `Map` seems much faster that `Object` (again, in my case).

Unfortunately, when iterating on my `Map` dictionary (a `Map` being iterable, so it can be directly iterated with `for...of`), I am facing the **"Iterate-and-Mutate" problem: when iterating on a `Map`, you are not supposed to mutate that same `Map` within iterations. That's an anti-pattern!**

With `Object` (which does not implement an iteration protocol, and so objects are not directly iterable using `for...of` by default), I am using `Object.keys()`, `Object.values()` or `Object.entries()` which returns an array of the given dictionary's own enumerable property names (keys), values or string-keyed property [key, value] pairs. Therefore, because I am not iterating on the dictionary itself, but actually on a separate `Array` in memory, I can write/mutate my dictionary safely, without facing any issue linked to the "Iterate-and-Mutate" problem.

When using `Map` as a dictionary and in order to iterate and mutate, one solution is to clone (either shallow or deep copy) the dictionary, then iterate on the original dictionary, but only mutate the clone. When the iteration cycle is finished, assign the clone to the original dictionary and delete the clone which is now useless. This requires having a clone of the original `Map` dictionary in memory which take unnecessary space.

Is there a better way to circumvent the "Iterate-and-Mutate" anti-pattern/problem associated with `Map` dictionary rather than cloning?

Thank you!

Examples:

1. `Object dictionary -> WORKS!`

```js
// Object dictionary -> WORKS!
const numbers = {
  '0': 0,
  '1': 1,
  '2': 2,
  '3': 3,
  '4': 4,
  '5': 5,
};

function compute(numbers) {
  /*
   * The Object.values() method returns an array of a given object's own
   * enumerable property values, in the same order as that provided by a
   * for...in loop.
   */
  for (number of Object.values(numbers)) {
    console.log('number:', number);

    const square = number * number;

    if (!numbers[`${square}`]) {
      numbers[`${square}`] = square;
    }
  }

  return numbers;
}

console.time('timer');
const result = compute(numbers);
console.timeEnd('timer');

console.log('result:', result);
```

2. `Map dictionary -> DOESN'T WORK AS IS!`

```js
// Map dictionary -> DOESN'T WORK AS IS!
const numbers = new Map([
  ['0', 0],
  ['1', 1],
  ['2', 2],
  ['3', 3],
  ['4', 4],
  ['5', 5],
]);

function compute(numbers) {
  /*
   * The values() method returns a new iterator object that contains the values
   * for each element in the Map object in insertion order.
   */
  for (number of numbers.values()) {
    console.log('number:', number);

    const squared = number * number;

    if (!numbers.has(`${squared}`)) {
      // "Iterate-and-Mutate" anti-pattern/problem:
      numbers.set(`${squared}`, squared);
    }
  }

  return numbers;
}

console.time('timer');
const result = compute(numbers);
console.timeEnd('timer');

console.log('result:', result);
```

3. `Map dictionary + clone (Deep Copy) -> WORKS!` (slow and take a lot of memory)

```js
// Map dictionary + clone (Deep Copy) -> WORKS!
let numbers = new Map([
  ['0', 0],
  ['1', 1],
  ['2', 2],
  ['3', 3],
  ['4', 4],
  ['5', 5],
]);

function compute(numbers) {
  /*
   * We create a clone (Deep Copy).
   * The data itself is cloned (slow and take a lot of memory).
   */
  const clone = new Map([ ...numbers.entries() ]);

  // Then, we iterate on the original dictionary.
  for (number of numbers.values()) {
    console.log('number:', number);

    const square = number * number;

    if (!clone.has(`${square}`)) {
      // But we mutate the clone, not the original dictionary.
      clone.set(`${square}`, square);
    }
  }

  // Finally, we assign 'clone' to original dictionary 'numbers'.
  numbers = clone;
  // And delete 'clone'.
  delete clone;

  return numbers;
}

console.time('timer');
const result = compute(numbers);
console.timeEnd('timer');

console.log('result:', result);
```

4. `Map dictionary + clone (Shallow Copy) -> WORKS!` (faster and take less memory than Deep Copy, but still ...)

```js
// Map dictionary + clone (Shallow Copy) -> WORKS!
let numbers = new Map([
  ['0', 0],
  ['1', 1],
  ['2', 2],
  ['3', 3],
  ['4', 4],
  ['5', 5],
]);

function compute(numbers) {
  /*
   * We create a clone (Shallow Copy).
   * The data itself is not cloned (faster and take less memory than Deep Copy).
   */
  const clone = new Map(numbers);

  // Then, we iterate on the original dictionary.
  for (number of numbers.values()) {
    console.log('number:', number);

    const square = number * number;

    if (!clone.has(`${square}`)) {
      // But we mutate the clone, not the original dictionary.
      clone.set(`${square}`, square);
    }
  }

  // Finally, we assign 'clone' to original dictionary 'numbers'.
  numbers = clone;
  // And delete 'clone'.
  delete clone;

  return numbers;
}

console.time('timer');
const result = compute(numbers);
console.timeEnd('timer');

console.log('result:', result);
```

5. `Map dictionary + fake clone -> DOESN'T WORK BECAUSE INSUFFICIENT!`

```js
// Map dictionary + fake clone -> DOESN'T WORK BECAUSE INSUFFICIENT!
let numbers = new Map([
  ['0', 0],
  ['1', 1],
  ['2', 2],
  ['3', 3],
  ['4', 4],
  ['5', 5],
]);

function compute(numbers) {
  /*
   * We create a "clone" (we believe we do, but in reality we don't!).
   * The 'clone' variable is not really a clone/copy of 'numbers'.
   * It's just a variable that points to the same data in memory.
   * Therefore, any mutation on 'numbers' will be reflected on 'clone',
   * which breaks the solution!
   */
  const clone = numbers;

  // Then, we iterate on the original dictionary.
  for (number of numbers.values()) {
    console.log('number:', number);

    const square = number * number;

    if (!clone.has(`${square}`)) {
      // But we mutate the clone, not the original dictionary.
      clone.set(`${square}`, square);
    }
  }

  // Finally, we assign 'clone' to original dictionary 'numbers'.
  numbers = clone;
  // And delete 'clone'.
  delete clone;

  return numbers;
}

console.time('timer');
const result = compute(numbers);
console.timeEnd('timer');

console.log('result:', result);
```

Comment: Where did you get the idea that mutating a Map instance while iterating is a bad thing to do?

Comment: @Pointy Thank you for your comment. Try running the examples 2 & 5 above, you will see that the number of iterations goes banana!

Comment: I actually like to make use of that behaviour when needing a queue.

Comment: "*This requires having a clone of the original Map dictionary in memory which take unnecessary space.*" - so does using `Object.keys`/`values`/`entries`.

Comment: "*We create a clone (Deep Copy). The data itself is cloned (slow and take a lot of memory): `new Map([ ...numbers.entries() ]);`*" - nope. What makes you think this is a deep copy? Also, this is not any different from `new Map([...numbers])` or just `new Map(numbers)`.

Comment: "*`delete clone;`*" - [this does not do what you think it does](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/)

Comment: @trincot Which behaviour? Which "queue"? May you precise please. Really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @Bergi "... `Object.keys()`, `Object.values()` or `Object.entries() which returns an array of the given dictionary's own enumerable property names (keys), values or string-keyed property [key, value] pairs." It's not exactly the same thing : here, you don't need to keep 2 `Map`s in memory, you just keep the original `Map` plus an `Array`, and if you use `Object.keys`, then you just have an array of keys. I understand that the examples given values are just primitive `Numbers`, but imagine that they were large `Object`. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: @EdouardBarthélémy There's not that much of a difference between an extra map and an  extra array; in both cases you need `O(n)` "unnecessary" space for the temporary structure. And no, using "large objects" (or strings or whatever) as keys/values doesn't make a difference either, since those are copied by reference (in both cases).

Comment: @Bergi `new Map(numbers)`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#cloning_and_merging_maps

> Note: Keep in mind that the data itself is not cloned.

Comment: @EdouardBarthélémy, I refer to the behaviour that what you *add* to a map will be iterated in a next iteration of the loop over that same map. I like to use that behaviour when the loop is about visiting nodes in a graph, and I discover more nodes to visit. See for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71342913/5459839) where a set `areas` is iterated and in the body of that loop `.add` is called on that set. It is the same principle. Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62682177/5459839) where the set is `visited`.

Comment: @EdouardBarthélémy Exactly - the MDN quote "*Keep in mind that the data itself is not cloned*" means that it's not a deep clone. And the same applies to `[...numbers]`.

Comment: @trincot Interesting! Indeed, that behaviour could be used for exploring growing data structures like graphs. In my case, I am not trying to expand iterations, but actually limit their expansion. Thank you for your insight!

Comment: @Bergi Okay, so despite the fact that we are creating a new `Array` and spreading the content of the `Map`, the underlying data is still at the same address in memory. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: @EdouardBarthélémy Yes, exactly. It simply copies the memory addresses of the keys and values. Whether you copy that into an array or a into a new map, or (unnecessarily) both, doesn't matter.

Comment: Indeed, all these statements create shallow copies. If you want a deep copy of the data you need to go through a `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(..))` or you can use the `structuredClone()` method!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to mimic the pattern that you use with a plain object (i.e. iterating over `Object.values`), then iterate `[...numbers.values()]`, which really is the Map equivalent for that. The space cost is similar -- in both cases an array is created that has the values.

So:

```js
const numbers = new Map([['0', 0],['1', 1],['2', 2],['3', 3],['4', 4],['5', 5]]);

function compute(numbers) {
  for (const number of [...numbers.values()]) {
    console.log('number:', number);
    const squared = number * number;
    if (!numbers.has(`${squared}`)) {
      numbers.set(`${squared}`, squared);
    }
  }
  return numbers;
}

console.log('result:', ...compute(numbers));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried with `Array.from(numbers.values())` before, and if I am not mistaking, it does the same thing as `[...numbers.values()]`. I don't know which one is less resource intensive, I haven't tried yet.

Comment: It's the same in this case. If you need to also map the values to still transform them, then `Array.from` is more interesting, as it accepts a second argument to do that mapping while the array is created.

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know about that projection function, very interesting!

Answer (score 1):

I have a possible solution but only in the case that you usually update only a small amount of items in the map. I think that maybe the case: you have a big amount of data and you update only some data each time.

In that scenary, you can work with 2 extra maps. You iterate your map: if a new key appears, you save in the updatesMap. If the content of an existing key has changes, you save that item in updatesMap. And if some key must be removed, you add this item in a removeMap map. So you only do changes in updatesMap and removeMap.

After iterate your map, you can iterate over updatesMap and add/update all their items in your original map. And finally, you can iterate over removeMap and delete all items in your original map.

removeMap can be a simple array with the keys to remove if you don't need the deleted values.

Comment: That's a very good idea. Actually, I thought about something similar in my sleep ... Thank you for reminding me, you're awesome!

Comment: Actually, it was me who whispered it to you while you were sleeping ;) glad to help.

Comment: Haha, you know what, I will try, benchmark it and let you know!

Comment: FYI, this is a good working solution, and looping on the mutations `Map` is faster than merging the two `Map`s like: `numbers = new Map([...numbers, ...mutations])`.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for sharing your tests. Glad to help